# WebView show Leaflet map with GraphHopper routing

Tags: javafx, webview, leaflet, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I am using the Leaflet API to show a map in a JavaFX application. I'm using a WebView to visualize the website with the map in my application. 
The application shows a driving simulation of a car between some points. 
If I use the OSMR Routing i don't have any problems to visualize the website & the map.

The problem is that I have to use the GraphHopper routing machine.

If I use the GraphHopper routing the control elements of the map will be shown, 
but the map is only grey.

If I open the website in a browser I don't have any problems.

Here is the Code of the map

```
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="rm/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
<script src="rm/lrm-graphhopper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
    ],
    router: L.Routing.graphHopper('Api-key'),
    routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
```

And this is the code of the javaFX application:

```
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webEngine.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/index.html").toExternalForm() );
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Are you using a valid api key? What is printed in the console? Are requests made? Are they all okay and just not visualized?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a valid api key. The problem is the request of the routing. It's https and not http. And the webview have some problems with the certificates i think.

Comment: Re certificates: are you using the latest Java version?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the version 1.8.0_102.

Comment: And I'm using the lrm-graphhopper library, not directly the graphhopper java api.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your map is not fully initialized until you have set the view. Try, for example:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([57.74, 11.94], 10);
```

or even just:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 0);
```

and you should see your map tiles and, hopefully, your route.